# What does an "&" before a pseudo element in CSS mean?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

In the following CSS taken from [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#misc) what does the ampersand (&) character mean?

```
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
  }
  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

Comment: In Sass and Less, the `&` is a reference to the parent selector.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

That's [LESS](http://lesscss.org), not CSS.

This syntax allows you to nest selector modifiers.

```
.clearfix { 
  &:before {
    content: '';
  }
}
```

Will compile to:

```
.clearfix:before {
  content: '';
}
```

With the `&`, the nested selectors compile to `.clearfix:before`.
Without it, they compile to `.clearfix :before`.

Comment: ok, but what's the difference with
```css
.clearfix { 
  :before {
    content: '';
  }
}
```
(without '&')
?

Answer (score 39):

A nested `&` selects the parent element in both SASS and LESS. It's not just for pseudo elements, it can be used with any kind of selector.

e.g.

```
h1 {
    &.class {

    }
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
h1.class {

}
```

Comment: when encountering such code it could also be https://github.com/postcss/postcss-nested

Answer (score 19):

Here is an SCSS/LESS example:

```
a {
   text-decoration: underline; 
   @include padding(15px);
   display: inline-block;

     & img  {
                padding-left: 7px;
               margin-top: -4px;
             }
 }
```

and its equivalent in CSS:

```
a {
  text-decoration: underline; 
  @include padding(15px);
  display: inline-block;
}

a img  {
     padding-left: 7px;
     margin-top: -4px;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

'&' is useful feature in both Sass and Less preprocessor. For nesting it's used. It is time saver when we compare to CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Found this on Google, needs a little update as **CSS nesting** is now native, rather than just the preserve of SASS (and other CSS processors).

You can find details about this here: [W3C - CSS Nesting Module  Working Draft, 14 February 2023](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/), while some examples can be seen here: [MDN - Using CSS nesting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting).

Both Chrome and Firefox support CSS Nesting. You can find the full browser support information here: [CanIUse? '&' CSS Nesting](https://caniuse.com/css-nesting)

It must be noted, though, there are some differences between the SASS and native implementation that won't allow you to just rename .sass to .css and hope things render correctly.

*(FAO MODS: I appreciate this isn't specifically a bootstrap answer, but it adds an up to date context. Hopefully that's OK)*

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35348681)

Answer (score 0):

> The parent selector, &, is a special selector invented by Sass that’s
> used in nested selectors to refer to the outer selector.

*A way to think about it, is that whenever an '&' is encountered in scss, it will be replaced by the parent selector when build in css.*

An excellent example from sass documentation is this.

This sass code:

```
.alert {
  // The parent selector can be used to add pseudo-classes to the outer
  // selector.
  &:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  // It can also be used to style the outer selector in a certain context, such
  // as a body set to use a right-to-left language.
  [dir=rtl] & {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  // You can even use it as an argument to pseudo-class selectors.
  :not(&) {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
}
```

will compile to this css:

```
.alert:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
[dir=rtl] .alert {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
:not(.alert) {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector/