# What does & do in css

Tags: css

I am looking at some legacy code and found something like below in the css file:

```
.user_modal {
  width: auto;
  height" auto;
  &.modal,
  &.fade.in
  {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:0;
    top:83px;
  }
 }
```

What is the purpose of the & here ?

Comment: That looks like a preprocessor stylesheet to me, not vanilla CSS. Are you sure the file you are looking at has the extension .css?

Comment: it's probably the parent selector reference in SASS. http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector. Anyway there's a syntax  error in `height" auto;` so if you compile this code with generate a SASS error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does an “&” before a pseudo element in CSS mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13608855/1529630)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably experienced with **[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)** selector. The **[ampersand](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)** `&` in sass is used to refer to the parent selector. So in your case `&` will refer to parent selector which is `.user_modal`

So `&.modal` which will be converted to CSS and become `.user_modal.modal`

so it'll match:

```
<div class='user_modal modal'></div>
```

the same way for `&.fade.in` which will match

```
<div class='user_modal fade in'></div>
```

So finally it's just become normal CSS after you've converted it:

```
.user_modal.modal , .user_modal.fade.in {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:0;
    top:83px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Sass or LESS. It's `user_modal` with those other classes in it that are not children of it. The `&` is a reference to the element/class above it.