# Avoid double writing styles

Tags: html, css, sass

I would like to know how I can avoid writing certain styles twice if they are the same for an element and it's possible pseudo classes:

```
.element {
  color: #a0c225;
  &:hover {
    color: #a0c225;
  }
  &:focus {
    color: #a0c225;
  }
}
```

and I don't want to repeat the color `#a0c225` in [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `&` to do something like this:

```
.element {
    &, &:hover, &:focus {
        color: #a0c225;
    }
}
```

Which would compile to:

```
.element, .element:hover, .element:focus {
    color: #a0c225;
}
```

Comment: @supersize Glad to be able to help

Comment: @Alex if you have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608855/what-does-an-before-a-pseudo-element-in-css-mean you will notice that an `&` sign is not CSS, it is SASS/LESS way of connecting selectors, so this is a valid answer which fits my needs the best!

Comment: yes you're right, for me it was just too close to css to need sass ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
$col-example: #a0c225;

%class-example {
  color: $col-example
}

.element {
  @extend %class-example;
  /* more properties */
  &:hover {
    @extend %class-example;
    /* more properties */
  }
  &:focus {
    @extend %class-example;
    /* more properties */
  }
}
```

which will compile to:

```
.element, .element:hover, .element:focus {
    color: #a0c225;
}

.element {
  /* more properties */
  &:hover {
    /* more properties */
  }
  &:focus {
    /* more properties */
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm pretty sure there is something like a `&` method that works. I don't necessarily need to store variables.

Comment: if you havent specified any other colors for focusing und hovering, the color will stay the same as in normal state at all