# What does &. mean in css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to replicate the following carousel in plunkr
but fail to do so, I just don't understand its css, like "&." and lots of parenthesis
Is there any way to help read this?

source:
https://codepen.io/mephysto/pen/ZYVKRY/

my replication:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5970D0m6hQrQDawSTOVo?p=preview

```
.multi-item-carousel{
  .carousel-inner{

.active{
  &.left{
    left:-33%;
  }

}
.next{
    left: 33%;
}
.prev{
  left: -33%;
}
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  > .item{
    // use your favourite prefixer here
    transition: 500ms ease-in-out all;
    backface-visibility: visible;
    transform: none!important;
  }
}
 }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608855/what-does-an-before-a-pseudo-element-in-css-mean

Comment: Please kindly read the documentation for SASS or LESS. This is SASS or LESS, not CSS.

Comment: It's a parent selector in SASS/LESS...CSS preprocessors.

Comment: Thanks all. I hv no idea about less. What should i do to run less css. It seems bootstrap css cant help