# Can't figure out what this react code means?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
if (propValue.indexOf('column') === 0) {
        output[`& > .${gridClasses.item}`] = {
          maxWidth: 'none',
        };
      }
```

Can anyone please explain this code?

Comment: if `propValue` starts with `"column"`, add a key called `"& > ." + gridClasses.item` to the `output` object with the value `{ maxWidth: .. }`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! And what does this  operator "& > ." mean??

Comment: It's not an operator. It's just a string. It's using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to add a variable to the string. If `gridClasses.item` value is `"header"`, it creates the object `output = { "& > .header" : { maxWidth: 'none' } }`. It's creating an object with CSS selectors as keys like https://stackoverflow.com/a/36167545/3082296